# Getting values from Oracle DB table into listbox in c# /wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

I cannot see any item  in my listbox when I use the code below. What is the problem? I tried to solve all day long but could not achieve to gather real values from the DB.I just got the list with blank items in it.

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Connectionn.ConnectionString))
        {


            OracleCommand cmdd = new OracleCommand(@"a random command which returns the values including combining two columns from two different tables", conn);

            conn.Open();
            cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            OracleDataReader dr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmdd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            //listboxReport.ItemsSource=dt.Rows; -tried-


            listboxReport.Items.Add(dt.Rows.ToString());
            listboxReport.DisplayMemberPath = dt.Columns[0].ToString();

            //listboxReport.Items.Add(dt.Rows);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Ok, i'm re-posting my answer using Oracle now:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            OracleCommand cmdd = new OracleCommand("select * from employees", conn);

            conn.Open();
            cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            OracleDataReader dr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmdd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            listboxReport.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
            listboxReport.DisplayMemberPath = dt.Columns[1].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I just searched for the solution all day long and did not encounter to any solution with 'AsDataView()'.This worked well.Thank you for your brief and understandable answer :)