# Load a combobox from oracle Database in c# WPF

Tags: c#, database, wpf, oracle, x11

I´m trying to fill a combobox with Oracle Database but I'm new in WPF.
What am I missing?
C# :

```
private void combonacionalidad_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ora.Open();
        OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand("select idnacionalidad, nacionalidad from nacionalidad ", ora);
        comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(comm);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        oda.Fill(ds);
        combonacionalidad.DisplayMemberPath = "nacionalidad";
        combonacionalidad.SelectedValuePath = "idnacionalidad";
    }
```

XAML :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combonacionalidad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="520,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Loaded="combonacionalidad_Loaded"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the `combonacionalidad.ItemSource` property to the data you want to use first in order to use `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` properties.
Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143489/getting-values-from-oracle-db-table-into-listbox-in-c-sharp-wpf) question as a source of information I've slightly modified your code, see if it works like this:

```
private void combonacionalidad_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ora.Open();
    OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand("select idnacionalidad, nacionalidad from nacionalidad ", ora);
    comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(comm);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    oda.Fill(dt);
    combonacionalidad.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
    combonacionalidad.DisplayMemberPath = "nacionalidad";
    combonacionalidad.SelectedValuePath = "idnacionalidad";
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you are missing the 
`cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and  `OracleDataReader dr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();` take a look at the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143489/getting-values-from-oracle-db-table-into-listbox-in-c-sharp-wpf)

Comment: idk why but its work to me adding what you say and this :using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Connectionn.ConnectionString))